# Smarty PHP Template Engine - file permission errors and missing templates

Tags: php, templates, smarty, file-permissions, smarty2

I am having a lot of headaches with the Smarty PHP Template Engine - Version 2.6.0 (smarty.net)

An error I keep getting in my error_log is

> PHP Fatal error:  Smarty error: unable to write to $compile_dir
>   '/var/www/vhosts/domain/library/templates/compiled'. Be sure
>   $compile_dir is writable by the web server user. in
>   /var/www/vhosts/domain/library/Smarty-2.6.0/libs/Smarty.class.php on
>   line 1088

I have made the folder and files writable with permissions set to 777 but still this error keeps happening.

It is making updating the template files a nightmare as currently I am updating the code in two places -> the templates folder and the compiled folder. It's like no compilation is happening so editing the already compiled file is the only way I can make a change to the site.

However, I had a template file that was being included in another template file and this was not in the compiled directory. After making a simple text change in this file has now completely removed that section of the site and the page just breaks that section is supposed to appear.

I am completely stumped with this and am hoping some of you with Smarty experience will be able to help me out.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you assign the compile dir in the smarty configuration file

here is sample of the config i use and it's working fine with me

```
/////Smarty including
require_once('libs/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->template_dir = 'template'; // template folder
$smarty->compile_dir = 'cache'; // Create a Folder Cache with 777 Permission
```

This Settings works fine with latest smarty edition Smarty 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the file httpd.conf

```
vim +231 /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

See what User and and Group are specified there,

if for example you see this:

```
User asterisk
Group asterisk
```

Then you need to give permission to that user/group on the directory **/var/www/**

```
chown -R asterisk:asterisk /var/www/
```